# Doubt about a theorem on the orders of an element and a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm reading *Theory of Groups of Finite Order* by W. Burnside, and I found this theorem stated:

> If an operation $S$, of order $n$, is permutable with a group
>   $\Gamma$; and if $S^m$ is the lowest power of $S$ which occurs in
>   $\Gamma$; then $m$ is a factor $n$, and $\frac{n}{m}$ is a factor of
>   the order of $\Gamma$.

The original text can be found here: [link](https://archive.org/stream/theorygroupsfin00burngoog#page/n66/mode/2up) (on the right page, theorem VIII)

Now, I dont' understand why the condition of $S$ being permutable with $\Gamma$ is required; even Burnside's proof doesn't seem, as I can understand, to use the stated condition.

Is then the following theorem true, or I am missing something?

> If $S$ is an element of order $n$, and if $S^m$ is the lowest power of $S$ which occurs in the subgroup $\Gamma$, then $m$ is a factor $n$, and $\frac{n}{m}$ is a factor of the order of $\Gamma$.

Comment: Yes, because $\langle S \rangle \cap \Gamma$ is a subgroup of $\Gamma$ generated by $S^m$ and of order $n/m$.